# ValueError when deriving new column in Python Pandas

Tags: python

I have a table with a column Exam score:

```
Exam Score  
120
700
1000
```

If the Exam score is >850 then we need to give A grade, if his score is between 801-850 we need to give him B and so on.

**My Task:** Need to create a column grade which will tell the students' grades

```
Grade           Exam score                         

A                           >850                            
B                            801-850                        
C                            751-800                        
D                            701-750                        
E                            651-700                        
F                            601-650                        
G                            550-600
```

**Code** is as follows:

```
workbook = pd.read_csv("Examscores_raw.csv")

def letter(row):
        if workbook['Exam score']>850:
            return 'A'
        elif (workbook['Exam score']>801):
            return 'B'
        elif (workbook['Exam score']>751):
            return 'C'
        elif (workbook['Exam score']>701):
            return 'D'
        elif (workbook['Exam score']>651):
            return 'E'
        elif (workbook['Exam score']>601):
            return 'F'
        elif (workbook['Exam score']>550):
            return 'G'
        else:
            return 'Fail'
 workbook['Grade']=workbook.apply (lambda row: letter(row), axis=1)
```

**Error** I am getting:

```
ValueError: ('The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or 
a.all().', 'occurred at index 0')
```

I went through many online answers but am unable to solve this. Kindly help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While @pissall's answer will work, The actual bug in the code you supplied, is in your def(letter) function you need to change all the workbooks to row. Also the lambda is not required and neither are the parentheses in the if. So you would have:

```
workbook = pd.read_csv("Examscores_raw.csv")

def letter(row):
        if row['Exam score']>850:
            return 'A'
        elif row['Exam score']>801:
            return 'B'
        elif row['Exam score']>751:
            return 'C'
        elif row['Exam score']>701:
            return 'D'
        elif row['Exam score']>651:
            return 'E'
        elif row['Exam score']>601:
            return 'F'
        elif row['Exam score']>550:
            return 'G'
        else:
            return 'Fail'
 workbook['Grade']=workbook.apply (letter, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can make the code somewhat easier:

```
# Declare conditions, and corresponding categories
conditions, type_choices = (
    [
        (df["exam_score"] >= 35),
        (df["exam_score"] < 35),
    ],
        ["Pass", "Fail"]
)

# Tag Pass/Fail based on the above conditions
df["result"] = np.select(conditions, type_choices, default="Fail")
```

Your use case:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
workbook = pd.read_csv("Examscores_raw.csv")

# Declare conditions, and corresponding categories
conditions, type_choices = (
    [
        (workbook["Exam score"] > 850),
        (workbook["Exam score"] > 801),
        (workbook["Exam score"] > 751),
        (workbook["Exam score"] > 701),
        (workbook["Exam score"] > 651),
        (workbook["Exam score"] > 601),
        (workbook["Exam score"] > 550),
        (workbook["Exam score"] <= 550),
    ],
        ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "Fail"]
)

# Tag Pass/Fail based on the above conditions
workbook["Grade"] = np.select(conditions, type_choices, default="Fail")
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you please help with how to resolve the error? My workbook is of type  pandas.core.frame.DataFrame. Is that correct or do I need to change the type of workbook etc.

Comment: @ShailajaGuptaKapoor It will work as it is. I will update my answer to suit your solution.

Comment: @ShailajaGuptaKapoor Please upvote if it helped :) Thanks

Comment: Upvoted and selected the answer as the correct answer :)

Comment: Hi one last thing if instead of exam grades I wanted to say give some numberic value 1,2,3,4,5 etc instead of A,B,C ,D .  Will replacing         ["A", "B", "C","Fail"] with ['1','2','3','4'] work?

Comment: @ShailajaGuptaKapoor You can use numbers/text